# PHP: Removing selected entries in an multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, youtube-api

for example I have this array called $test and all of the sub-arrays inside are called 'link',

```
array(6) {
[0] = > array(3) {
 ["link"] = > string(56)
    "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.subscriptions" ["href"] = > string(67)
    "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/test/subscriptions" ["countHint"] = > int(1)
}[link] = > array(3) {
    ["rel"] = > string(51)
    "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.contacts" ["href"] = > string(62)
    "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/test/contacts" ["countHint"] = > int(0)
}[link] = > array(2) {
    ["rel"] = > string(48)
    "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.inbox" ["href"] = > string(59)
    "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/test/inbox"
}[link] = > array(2) {
    ["rel"] = > string(52)
    "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.playlists" ["href"] = > string(63)
    "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/test/playlists"
}[link] = > array(3) {
    ["rel"] = > string(50)
    "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.uploads" ["href"] = > string(61)
    "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/test/uploads" ["countHint"] = > int(22)
}[link] = > array(2) {
    ["rel"] = > string(64)
    "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.newsubscriptionvideos" ["href"] = > string(75)
    "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/test/newsubscriptionvideos"
}
```

}

How will I get the sub-array 'link' that has the `["href"] = > string(61)"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/test/uploads"` content. Thanks!

Comment: I tried to recreate your array but it seems I only get one sub-array since it is using the same index named "link". Or maybe I am missing something here

Answer (score 0):

```
$search = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/test/uploads';
$match = null;
foreach ($linkArray as $link) {
     if ($link['href'] == $search) {
          $match = $link;
     }
}
```

I think something like that will do the work for you.
$linkArray is the array you posted